Finding light bulbs that work properly with "2-way" lamps
I recently thrifted a pair of lamps and am having trouble finding proper light bulbs for them. Although most all lamps I'm familiar with either have a binary on/off or a three-way off/low/medium/high, these are two-way lights: turning the knob once puts it on a low-power output, a second turn to full power, then a third turns it off.
However, browsing the local hardware store and even googling hasn't turned up any two-way bulbs. My google searches only return unhelpful results like socket splitters, dual LED bulbs that switch brightness if the power is toggled quickly, hypothetical "could there be such thing as a two-way bulb?" Quora/reddit posts, or irrelevant results like "2 pack of 3-way bulbs". Nothing close to what I'm looking for.
I've tried using various bulbs I already have around the home to little success. Standard, dimmable, or 3-way the result is almost universally that on "low" the bulb is flickering to some degree (and in some cases not even appreciably less bright than the "high" setting), then on "high" it is bright and stable.
The safety label on the lamp reads:

CAUTION: TO REDUCE THE RISK OF FIRE USE 100 WATT TYPE A LAMP MAX.
120V 60Hz AC ONLY MADE IN TAIWAN E86924 ID113 ALÄNG

("ALÄNG" is the Ikea model name - this specific model of floor/table lamp has been discontinued, and although I have found copies of the manual online, they provide no specifications for bulbs.)
I'm not sure what to try next. All the bulbs I've tested have been LEDs, should I try incandescent or halogen bulbs? Replace the lamp sockets with a more common 1- or 3-way? Put up with the mild flickering? Just get used to having to turn the knob twice?

E86924 seems to be an Ikea SKU. Ikea parts department may have a modernised controller that allows using these lamps with led bulbs.

Not really an answer so putting this as a comment.  I think typically for something like this that a diode is put into the electrical path to give "half power", so rather than the bulb getting a full wave input voltage, it's only getting a half wave.  Or, effectively it's seeing 30Hz input rather than 60Hz, since half of the AC wave is getting cut off by the diode.  This works just fine for incandescent bulbs, but messes with electronics of LED of CFLs that expect the full 60Hz input frequency.

If you've never seen these things in operation, how do you know they're 2-way?

Everything points to this being some sort of fancy dimmer switch.

100 WATT TYPE A LAMP MAX

Clearly incandescent, so pre-dates the LED revolution and decent compact fluorescents. (Unrelated, but for a number of years I found Ikea was the best place around to get reasonably priced, good quality compact fluorescents. So this must be an old lamp.)

the result is almost universally that on "low" the bulb is flickering to some degree (and in some cases not even appreciably less bright than the "high" setting)

That is classic for a non-LED-compatible dimmer.

turning the knob once puts it on a low-power output, a second turn to full power, then a third turns it off.

That indicates some sort of electronic solution to providing two light levels. Why? Because the reason a 3-way bulb works the way it does is that it has two filaments (incandescent) or two groups of LEDs, with a different "hot" connection for each. Once you have those two - which is the minimum way to switch things using simple switches, you automatically have a 3rd option. So having exactly 2 options is an indication that the change in light is not by connecting differently (a 3-way bulb) but by reducing the power (a.k.a., dimming).
The way to confirm this is to unplug the lamp, unscrew the bulb and look inside the bulb socket. If it has the standard button on the bottom and either a single metal connection or a single "ring" (more common) then this is indeed designed for a single ordinary bulb, but not compatible with modern bulbs.
If you see two separate pieces of metal where there would normally be a "ring" (unlikely), or if you see two separate rings (unlikely) then this is an oddball variant of 3-way that needs a special bulb to make it work. But I highly doubt that will be the case.

From Wikipedia, here's a pic that illustrates this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-way_lamp#/media/File:3Way_Bulb_Contacts.jpg

A cheap way of providing two-way dimmable light is simply to add a diode into the circuit. On the low power setting the power goes through the diode into the lamp. On the high power setting the power goes directly to the lamp. The diode blocks one half of the AC cycle, so you get less power. This is utterly simple, and it pretty much works. But an LED lamp won't like it; you need an incandescent bulb.

The Flickering described in the question is common symptom of such a diode dimmer.

These may be using the old trick if putting two bulbs in parallel for bright, series for dim...  Thought I'm not convinced that's better than just turning off one of the bulbs. All guesswork until we dissect one, though.
